# Java/Android - AlarmManager battery Consumer?

Tags: java, android, performance, alarmmanager, batterylevel

In our `firebase` security application, we use an `Android AlarmManger` to keep alive our `firebase` listener.

`AlarmManager` scheduled via a `BroadcastReceiver` when the device booted up
The alarm wake up CPU each 5 sec and check if `firebase` listener is ready else start it.

Using the pattern we noticed an impact on battery life
Could you please advice the best pattern ?

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(context);
        FirebaseUtils.startListeners(context);

        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
       am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }
}
```

Comment: Alarm manger wake CPU even when mobile is in sleep mode thats why It consume battery.

Comment: Increase your repeating interval.

Comment: @Bansal thanks for your replay, in the case have you any idea how app  like viber, skyp work ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing your repeating interval, if you really dont need to repeat at every 5 seconds.App broadcast at every 5 seconds is same like playing with the app constantly.Try making it 30 or 50 secs.

Comment: After increasing the repeating interval to 50 secs,the result Is better but is not accepted, any other ideas ? please advice